# How Do You Make Bootstrap Responsive Tables Wider

Tags: html, css, html-table, bootstrap-5

I'm using bootstrap 5 to create responsive tables which works fine but when one column has a lot of text all other columns get squished making it look weird. I would like to set it so that the columns with smaller amounts of texts and the table headers to not get cut off. I also have the table set to responsive which in bootstrap's css sets overflow-x: auto.

[Picture of what the table looks like on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nD94C.png)

[Second Picture of mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsX48.png)

[Picture of what it looks like on pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zx3KY.png)

```html
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">    
</head>
<div class="container"> 
   <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead class="table-warning">  
                <tr>  
                    <th scope="col">Ticket ID</th> 
                    <th scope="col">Asset Type Or User</th>
                    <th scope="col">Asset Tag</th>
                    <th scope="col">User ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>  
                    <th scope="col">Location</th> 
                    <th scope="col">Description</th> 
                    <th scope="col">Date Added</th> 
                    <th scope="col">Priority</th> 
                    <th scope="col">Mark As Done</th>
                </tr>  
            </thead>  
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">4</th>
                    <td>computer</td>
                    <td>C-Place-Holder</td>
                    <td>NA</td>
                    <td>Tom Blow</td>
                    <td>In Health Building, Bottom Floor</td>
                    <td>User would like to print color, has missing files, and monitor is flickering.</td>
                    <td>2021-02-24</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="4" onclick="markDone(4)">Done</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you need the columns wider, then it looks like it requires a horizontal scroll. which is the most common approach for small screen devices

Answer (score 1):

To make it 100% you have to add this command to your CSS
`.table-responsive { display: table; }` but this won't work for smaller screens. You have to use media queries for that.
Hope my answer helps you.